# Buscando Geolocalização do google no angular

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Olá, tenho que buscar a Longitude e Latitude, pela API do Google, com Angular..

Estou utilizando esse código para realizar a requisição:

```html
constructor(private http: Http, private vwServicePagination: VwServicePagination){}

    obtendoGeolocalizacao() {  
        return this.http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=09771220')
            .map(response => response.json());
    }
```

E aqui no OnInit estou chamando esse metodo criado acima... Desta forma:

```html
ngOnInit(){
        const teste = this.vwServiceApi.obtendoGeolocalizacao();
        
        console.log(this.teste);
    }
```

Porém, o objeto retornado não tem nada haver com o json que é retornado pela API! Como consigo obter o objeto JSON retornado pela API?

Comment: vc tem que usar o subscribe,  this.vwServiceApi.obtendoGeolocalizacao().subscribe(resposta=> console.log(resposta))

Comment: Boa, 

Usei da seguinte forma, se quiser colar na sua resposta...






ngOnInit(){       
         this.vwServiceApi.obtendoGeolocalizacao().subscribe(res => {this.apiGoogle = res.json();
            
            const lat = this.apiGoogle.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
            const lng = this.apiGoogle.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
        });

        this.concessionarias = this.vwServiceApi.concessionarias();
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizei da seguinte forma para conseguir o objeto...

```html
this.vwServiceApi.obtendoGeolocalizacao().subscribe(res => {this.apiGoogle = res.json();                
                this.lat = this.apiGoogle.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                const lng = this.apiGoogle.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
                const uf = this.apiGoogle.results[0].address_components[3].short_name;               
            });
```